regex to interpret awkward scientific notation
Ok, so I'm working with this ENDF data, see here. Sometimes in the files they have what is quite possibly the most annoying encoding of scientific notation floating point numbers I have ever seen1. There it is often used that instead of 1.234e-3 it would be something like 1.234-3 (omitting the "e").
Now I've seen a library that simply changes - into e- or + into e+ by a simple substitution. But that doesn't work when some of the numbers can be negative. You end up getting some nonsense like e-5.122e-5 when the input was -5.122-5.
So, I guess I need to move onto regex? I'm open to another solution that's simpler but its the best I can think of right now. I am using the re python library. I can do a simple substitution where I look for [0-9]-[0-9] and replace that like this:
import re
str1='-5.634-5'
x = re.sub('[0-9]-[0-9]','4e-5',str1)
print(x)

But obviously this won't work generally because I need to get the numerals before and after the - to be what they were, not just something I made up... I've used capturing groups before but what would be the fastest way in this context to use a capturing group for the digits before and after the - and feed it back into the substitution using the Python regex library import re?
1 Yes, I know, fortran...80 characters...save space...punch cards...nobody cares anymore.

Does a lookbehind assertion work for you? re.sub('(?<=[0-9])-','e-',str1)

If you want to know which is faster just measure them (i.e. time it)

...80 characters...nobody cares anymore. - you seriously think fixed-length records are a thing of the past?

There is a pip package called endf that would probably be suitable for your purposes.

@Woodford I think they're decrying the character saving omission of the implied e in 1.234-5 to help meet an 80 character limit, not fixed length records.

@dROOOze didn't appreciate your comment until now, yes that's a great idea. In fact I guess it's the basis for the regex solution below. Although matching the spaces is neat.

Probably wouldn't reach for regex for this, when some simple string ops should work:
s.replace("-", "e-").replace("+", "e+").lstrip("e")


I´d go for something along this - what makes me feel uncomfortable is that it wouldn't work straightforward for numbers with a positive exponent - but I understand this may work for the O.P. . And then, for something that can catch at once [+-] we are in regexp land already. (in my more antirexp grumpy days I wouldn't mind curying two .replace just to avoid then either )

Using string split, or outright replace could take care of this.
But a regexp, using Python's re.sub method can take care of it in a single line as well, covering all edge cases (leading signal, etc...):
import re
str1='-5.634-5'
num = float(re.sub(r"([0-9\-+.][0-9.]*)([\-+])(\d+)", r"\1e\2\3", str1))
print(num)

reading as: the first char can be either +-. or a digit, followed by a sequence of digit or ., then a signal indicating the exponent signal, then some digits for the exponent. Just add an "e" to the middle group - and while we are at it, convert it to "float" at once to get rid of possible leading "+" :-)

this is excellent, and useful for upping my regex game, thanks! Accepted the other answer purely for expedience of this situation.

You can match the gap to substitute with e by asserting that it is not preceded by the beginning of the string and is followed by - or +:
import re

str1='-5.634-5'
print(re.sub('(?<!^)(?=[-+])', 'e', str1))

This outputs:
-5.634e-5


awesome, thanks for this knowledge! accepted the shorter answer but this is probably more elegant for a generalized parser.

Also, for others: I've never used gap matching in regex before. I found modeling this on https://regex101.com/ and realizing that the phrases 'lookahead' or 'lookbehind' or 'lookbehind assertion' are useful search phrases. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups

I would do something along these lines.
You can simultaneously validate that the number is the format that you expect and capture the constituent parts with a regex:
import re 

cases=['-5.634-5','1.234-3','1.234+3','-1.234+3','1+2','-1-2']

for s in cases:
    if m:=re.search(r'^([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d*)?)([+-]\d+)$', s):
        f=float(f'{m.group(1)}e{m.group(2)}')
        print('{0!r:10}\t=>\t{1}'.format(s, f))
    else:
        continue
        # not a good number

Prints:
'-5.634-5'  =>  -5.634e-05
'1.234-3'   =>  0.001234
'1.234+3'   =>  1234.0
'-1.234+3'  =>  -1234.0
'1+2'       =>  100.0
'-1-2'      =>  -0.01

